# How to open busy serial port (share port) with pyserial

Tags: windows, pyserial

Is it possible open serial port which already in use?
and send data to it

Or create new one and share it for few applications?

I'm trying to avoid use of port pairs (created by windows driver)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use an intemediate program like Hyperterminal and sendkeys to it from other apps, ao that Hyperterminal sends them from multiple sources.

Other than a workaround like that I've never heard of a port beng open in more than one program simultaneously.